# Bug: Editing tags on a question in review queue causes tag pop-up box to be cut-off / hidden by the footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tagging, editing

I noticed this yesterday while editing but didn't have time to post it. It appears to be the same as this: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/997/bug-tag-pop-out-is-truncated-by-layout-if-question-preview-is-longer *but* it was while I was editing a question in the review queue.

Additionally, when in edit mode in the review queue, the question vote counter disappeared - I don't know if that's by design or not.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be fixed but I was only able to test it in a close vote review. I will test it on a first question review when I see one